# Consuming REST based web services in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, rest

Greetings,

I'm confused as to the best approach to make when consuming REST based web services with .Net. At the moment I'm using the System.net.webclient class. Should I be using Webresponse, webrequest classes in System.Net ?

If I were to use another approach (Other than webclient) what disadvantages / advantages would I gain ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the [WCF REST starter kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx), there's pretty much no technical downside.  There's a learning curve, however, and it will only work if you have .Net 3.5 SP1 (so I guess that's the down side).

Answer (score 3):

You can also see [this link](http://aspguy.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/dealing-with-rest-web-services/) if you want to do it without WCF.