# How to post JSON data from asp.net mvc 3 to web service

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consuming REST based web services in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727649/consuming-rest-based-web-services-in-net)

I have the project of asp.net MVC, and my partner works on RESTFUL web service. Then I'm the one who post the JSON data to the web service. But I never work with posting data to web service. Could anyone give me any idea of how to posting JSON data to Restful using asp.net mvc 3.0.

Thanks for any help anyone can give me!

Comment: Are you trying to consume the web service on the server (with C#/VB.NET/etc) or on the client (with JavaScript)?

Comment: I am trying to do it with C# of my asp.net mvc 3.0 controller. I have a button, then if I click on it, it will point to that controller.

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo : Do I have to do it with JavaScript?

Comment: No.  A quick search shows there is [plenty of help available already](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/727649/consuming-rest-based-web-services-in-net).

Comment: @JamesD'Angelo : The second answer of that question is using with XML not JSON data, right?

Comment: [Another link to check out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682560/best-way-to-consume-json-from-rest-api-in-net). (It will probably be faster to search than get another answer here.)